# Complicated output from simple Eigenvalues problem

Tags: functions, numerics

I have code that uses Eigenvalues on matrices of various sizes.  But the output of what should be a very simple problem, namely finding the eigenvalue of a 1x1 matrix, is overly complicated.

```
Eigenvalues[{{1-(0.2494562342391921 Exp[-2(-0.2+x)^2]+0.769722872465748 Exp[-2x^2])/(1-x^2)}}]
```

returns

```
(3.28871*10^-17 E^(-2 (-0.2+x)^2-2 x^2) (2.3405*10^16 E^(2 (-0.2+x)^2)+7.58524*10^15 E^(2 x^2)-3.04071*10^16 E^(2 (-0.2+x)^2+2 x^2)+3.04071*10^16 E^(2 (-0.2+x)^2+2 x^2) x^2))/(-1.+x^2)
```

Where did those 10^-17 and 10^16 terms come from?  Why can't it just give me

```
1-(0.2494562342391921 Exp[-2(-0.2+x)^2]+0.769722872465748 Exp[-2x^2])/(1-x^2)
```

?

Comment: The eigencode probably tried to factor a symbolic expression. That gets dicey when there are approximate numbers involved.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: a nasty side-effect is that `Chop` produces zero while `FullSimplify` acts as desired.

Comment: @Wouter I assure you that particular side effect has bitten me more times, and in more delicate places, than I can describe in this forum.

Comment: @Wouter: Yes, the interaction with Chop is exactly why I asked.  In the end, I now check for 1x1 matrix and not send it through Eigenvalues unnecessarily, which sidesteps this issue.